# Trying to understand AVAudioPlayer and audio level metering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to understand AVAudioPlayer and audio level metering. What I have below is an object "AudioPlayer" that is playing a short audio sound. Now I want to output the power of this sound (decibels). Somehow I don't think I'm doing this right.

```
        audioPlayer.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [audioPlayer play];
        int channels = audioPlayer.numberOfChannels;
        [audioPlayer updateMeters];
        for (int i=0; i<channels; i++) {
            //Log the peak and average power
            NSLog(@"%d %0.2f %0.2f", i, [audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0],[audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0]);
```

The NSLog output of this is
0 -160.00 -160.00
1 -160.00 -160.00

Now according to Apple "A return value of 0 dB indicates full scale, or maximum power; a return value of -160 dB indicates minimum power" So does this mean this sound is at minimum power? I don't think this is true because the audio snippet is a fairly loud sound. I think I'm missing something here, any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're updating and then asking for the value of the meters almost immediately after the sound starts -- that `updateMeters` is probably running a few tens of milliseconds after you send `play`. So if there's any silence at the beginning of the clip, you could very well be getting the correct reading. You should trying delaying your inspection, and you may also need to send `updateMeters` *inside* the loop, right before you inspect the values.

You're also never actually getting the meter values for channels > 0, because you pass 0 no matter what the value of `i` is in the loop. I think you meant to do this:

```
for (int currChan = 0; currChan < channels; currChan++) {
    //Log the peak and average power
    NSLog(@"%d %0.2f %0.2f", currChan, [audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:currChan], [audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:currChan]);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are several issues with your code - Jacques has already pointed out most of them.

You have to call `[audioPlayer updateMeters];` each time before reading the values.
You'll probably be best off instantiating a `NSTimer`.

Declare an iVar `NSTimer *playerTimer;` in your class `@interface`.

Also it doesn't hurt to adopt `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>` in your class so you'll be able to invalidate the timer after player has finished playing.

Then change your code to:

```
audioPlayer.meteringEnabled = YES;
audioPlayer.delegate = self;

if (!playerTimer)
{
    playerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
                  target:self selector:@selector(monitorAudioPlayer)
                userInfo:nil
                 repeats:YES];
}

[audioPlayer play];
```

Add this two methods to your class:

```
-(void) monitorAudioPlayer
{   
    [audioPlayer updateMeters];
    
    for (int i=0; i<audioPlayer.numberOfChannels; i++)
    {
        //Log the peak and average power
         NSLog(@"%d %0.2f %0.2f", i, [audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:i],[audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:i]);
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{   
    NSLog (@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:");
    [playerTimer invalidate];
    playerTimer = nil;
}
```

And you should be good to go.