# AVPlayer Live stream how to get power for audio level metering

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am trying to show a meter graph in my app which uses AVPlayer to stream live audio streams.

I know for AVAudioPlayer there is a way as per:
[Trying to understand AVAudioPlayer and audio level metering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504428/trying-to-understand-avaudioplayer-and-audio-level-metering)

which uses `peakPowerForChannel`

But AVAudioPlayer doesn't work for audio streams.

Is there something similar for AVPlayer? Or is there any other way I can get the power values from the AVPlayer?

Code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    if (self.avplayer) {
        [self.avplayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
    }
    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://broadcast.infomaniak.net/radionova-high.mp3"] options:nil];
    NSArray *keys = @[@"playable"];
    [avAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            AVPlayerItem *newItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];
            if (!self.avplayer) {
                self.avplayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:newItem];
            } else {
                [self.avplayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newItem];
            }
            [self.avplayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
            [self.avplayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
        });
    }];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"%@ called",keyPath);
    if ( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        [self.avplayer play];
    } else if ( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        if (self.avplayer.rate) {
            NSLog(@"Playing...");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"currentPlayingChangedToPlay" object:nil];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not playing...");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"currentPlayingChangedToPause" object:nil];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension

Answer (score 4):

Ordinarily, you can get at the audio samples of an `AVPlayer` by using an `MTAudioProcessingTap` on the player item, however your asset resists this through

1. the `tracks` property on your `AVURLAsset` never becoming available
2. not calling you back when you observe and attach the tap to your `playerItem.tracks`'s `assetTrack`.

I've never seen a good explanation for why this doesn't work for remote `mp3`s or `m3u8` streams, and annoyingly, it does work for other remote asset types, like `aac`. Unjustly, on the video side, [AVPlayerItemVideoOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553034/22147) seems to work for all types of assets (barring DRM problems)!

So where does this leave you? One way is to stream the mp3 data yourself from where you can decode and play it using an `AudioQueue`, and *also* calculate the peak power using the aforementioned `MTAudioProcessingTap`. Solutions involving `AudioConverter`/`AudioUnit` and `AVAudioConverter`/`AVAudioEngine` come to mind too.

If that sounds like too much work just to replace a single property, you could look at pre-baked solutions, like [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit/) or [FreeStreamer](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer) and then calculate power. You may find a library that calculates power for you. If not, you can calculate `peakPowerForChannel` using [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845967/22147)