# AVPlayer Live stream how to get power for audio level metering, something new?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I know there are many questions regarding this topic but no real answer so far. I start a new request on that topic. The best answers are here but no solution. Is there a practicable way in the meantime?

[AVPlayer Live stream how to get power for audio level metering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947408/avplayer-live-stream-how-to-get-power-for-audio-level-metering)

I am using the following code to play the audio stream for that kind of links I would need the audio metering:

```
playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mp3stream7.apasf.apa.at:8000"]]];

player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

[player play];
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this link is helping you
https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit